# How to conditionally compile member based on class template

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to conditionally compile a member of a class based on it's class template parameter. I have convenience functions that only make sense to the compiler in certain conditions so I'd like for the compiler to skip them if I can programmatically determine when this is so.

```
// T is a mathematical type
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    // when zero is not clearly defined
    void bar(T a, T b, T zero) {

    }

    // only makes sense if 0 can be cast to T
    // will fail otherwise
    void bar(T a, T b) {
        bar(a, b, 0);
    } 
}
```

- I am using VS2012, so sadly, no default member template parameters. :(

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you mean template specializations? I can't get what you're actually asking for :/ ...

Comment: Hm... that is a problem...

Comment: You need to show us a minimal code example..

Comment: May be this helps: [Conditional type selection using C++ template specializations](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2014/02/conditional-type-selection-using-c.html)

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm after. I'm looking for something along the lines of SFINAE.

Comment: Yeah, template specializations are definitely going to be your only option here. ``#ifdef`` is a preprossor macro, so it will be evaluated before the template types are, and thus before the auto specializations are.

Comment: I guess you could leave the code as you show it.  There will only be a compile error if somebody tries to actually use the second `bar`.  A `static_assert` in the second `bar` could make the error message more obvious.

Comment: @PythonNut _'I don't think that's what I'm after'_ It pretty much applies the essentials of SFINAE IMHO.

Comment: Perhaps you can check std::enable_if: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: Check the duplicate, the example I used on the answer is very similar to your problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code in your link doesn't use any SFINAE at all.